# Calculating GPS "satellite view" from ground points as proportion of sky traversed by satellites and unobstructed by topography

Tags: qgis, gps

I'm a wildlife biologist trying to conduct a habitat selection analysis for GPS collared animals in western Washington State. There appears to be greater GPS error and more missing locations in areas with dense canopy cover and more rugged terrain, which is leading to substantial bias in my model results.

I want to correct for that bias by building a logistic regression model for the probability of obtaining a successful GPS location based on canopy cover and satellite view at each 30m x 30m raster pixel of my study area. I want to calculate "satellite view" by doing the following for each pixel:

1. Generate a sky plot representing the unobstructed viewshed from the center point of each raster pixel
2. Generate vector lines for the paths of all GPS satellites traversing that viewshed within a given 24 hour period
3. Generate 1 to 5 points along those paths in each cardinal and semi cardinal direction at 15, 30, 45, 60, and 75 degrees above the horizon
4. Calculate the percentage of those points obstructed by topography using a DEM layer.

This procedure is modeled after a 2007 paper in the same study area: https://wildlife.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.2193/2006-367?casa_token=-B5nBxl1vOcAAAAA:tgD_MOVZNbpcZh_TSS8r9tpUFG_Y_jrHjLhJnHr6H2H1ZaS0GfiG4TZT6qcrI7X2AeHAPDGsBGtcntBd

**The Problem:**

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to get the satellite paths into QGIS as vectors to generate points for viewshed analysis.

The authors of the paper did their analysis using the Quick Plan tool in GPS Pathfinder Office, but that tool no longer appears to be available.

The Trimble online GNSS plannning tool gives me the sky plot I need for one location at a time but isn't iterative or exportable: https://www.gnssplanning.com/

I'm aware of NASA's CDDIS GNSS database at https://cddis.nasa.gov/ and the TLE files available at https://celestrak.org/, but I'm having trouble parsing them into a format I can use in QGIS. There appear to be some tools for doing this in MATLAB and Python, but I do most of my work in R and am not very familiar with those platforms. Does anyone have any advice on how to accomplish this or other methods to correct for GPS bias due to canopy cover and terrain?

Thanks!

[image: Here's a figure from the above paper representing what I'm trying to do]

Comment: There may be other ways to generate the trajectories you want - Google "calculate satellite trajectory from ephemeris data", that may offer some options.   As a side comment, I hope you're not only using GPS these days - adding GLONASS, Galileo, Beidou will hugely increase the number of available satellites and under Washington State vegetation.